# Programmatically modify MapTip Expression

Tags: arcgis-engine, shapefile

If I load a layer via a shapefile and set

```
((ILayer)myLayer).ShowTips = true;
```

How can I change the tip content (I want to point it to a different column or have a expression of multiple columns) programatically with ArcEngine 10 and C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [DisplayField](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/DisplayField_Property/0012000004ts000000/) on the IFeatureLayer for changing attribute field. For more advanced formating check out the [IDisplayString](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IDisplayString_Interface/0012000003v7000000/) and [IDisplayExpressionProperties](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IDisplayExpressionProperties_Interface/0012000003tz000000/).

Made some code this work for me:

```
private void startMapTipsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ILayer layer = axMapControl1.Map.get_Layer(0);
            axMapControl1.ShowMapTips = true;
            IFeatureLayer fLayer = layer as IFeatureLayer;

            fLayer.ShowTips = true;
            fLayer.DisplayField = "AREANAME";

        }

        private void startMapTipsAdvancedToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ILayer layer = axMapControl1.Map.get_Layer(0);
            axMapControl1.ShowMapTips = true;
            IFeatureLayer fLayer = layer as IFeatureLayer;

            fLayer.ShowTips = true;

            IDisplayString displayString = fLayer as IDisplayString;
            IDisplayExpressionProperties properties = displayString.ExpressionProperties;

            properties.Expression = "[AREANAME] & vbnewline & [POP2000]";
        }
```

Comment: I did that and got no errors, but the tips don't display, do you have any ideas about why they wouldn't display

Comment: @iterationx, exactly what did you do?

Comment: IFeatureLayer thisFeatureLayer = thisLayer as IFeatureLayer;
thisFeatureLayer.DisplayField = "OWNER_NAME";
thisFeatureLayer.ShowTips = true;

Comment: @iterationx, I've added some code that work for me.

Comment: Thanks, my problem was that I had not enabled MapTips via axMapControl1.ShowMapTips = true;

Answer (score 1):

> **ILayer.ShowTips Property**: Indicates whether or not map tips are shown for the layer. If set to True, then map tips will be shown for the layer. You can determine the text that will be shown via TipText. For a FeatureLayer, this text comes from the data for IFeatureLayer::DisplayField.

In your case that would be a simple

```
((IFeatureLayer)myLayer).DisplayField = "colName";
```